# Any reason not to silicone caulk around glass shower brackets?

Tags: shower, leak, glass, brackets, silicone

I’ve had the glass installers come by to fix, but I’m wondering if there’s any reason I should not fully silicone caulk around the brackets that hold the glass in place.  The company has only caulked around the base of the inside where the glass meets the stone, but not the tops or sides of the brackets.  The leak looks to only come from the brackets.  It seems to me the water is dripping down the glass and through the top of the uncaulked bracket.  Also is there any reason not to silicone the outside where the glass meets the stone.

Thanks![image]

Comment: Is there caulk on the inside at the intersection of the metal bracket & the sill? It's hard to tell for certain from the picture, but there does look to be something between the metal bracket and glass, but that could just be some moisture on the glass above that intersection and it just appears that way in the picture.

Comment: How long did you leave the caulk to set?  Should be no reason not to seal the brackets also.  Doing the outside is usually just an expense without much/any benefit.

Comment: That looks like a terrible design...you have water coming through between the glass panels.  Also, caulking should be done *inside* the shower, not outside.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the caulked after the brackets so there's no caulk between them.

Just caulk up and around them inside the shower

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).